# Select vertices of mesh in python

Tags: python, scripting, mesh, selection-tools

What is the python way to select vertices of a mesh?

I've tried:

```
for vert in obj.data.vertices:  
    vert.select = True
```

I ran the above code in edit mode, but the vertices didn't turn yellow.

Comment: related : http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-200305.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import bpy,bmesh

ob   = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
mesh = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(ob.data)
for v in mesh.verts:
    v.select = True

# trigger viewport update
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
```

[Docs](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bmesh.html?highlight=bmesh.from_edit_mesh#bmesh.from_edit_mesh)

Comment: What's the need for the `ob` variable?

Comment: I believe it's just so you don't have to keep typing `bpy.data.objects['Cube']`, for instance, where it's accessed again in `bmesh.from_edit_mesh(ob.data)`

Comment: thanks for this simple example. arent we suppose to free the bmesh after ?

Comment: When trying this in Blender 2.91 it complains that "The mesh must be in editmode"..

Comment: @user299831 bmesh.from_edit_mesh requires you being in edit mode for the object initially.