# Select objects in a specified region with python

Tags: python, objects

He there,

is there a way to select all objects in a predefined region via python?
Let's say i've got a complex scene and I want to select all objects that are located somwhere within the bounding of 0,0,-5 to 10,15,15
Just like the border select tool does but then within the given coordinates.
thanks already

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472049/check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangular-shaped-area-3d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74162/selecting-vertices-within-a-box-defined-by-exact-coordinates/74166#74166) answer, as it is similiar.

My example will handle an XYZ bounding box with perpendicular edges only. Otherwise look into batFINGER's [suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1472080).

- [object_matrix_world](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/bpy.types.Object.html?#bpy.types.Object.matrix_world)
- [to_translation](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix.to_translation)

Paste the code into Blender's Text Editor and press "Run Script".

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector


# checks if a supplied coordinate if in the bounding box created by vector1 and vector2
# vector_check           the vector which is compared against the bounding box
# vector1                     the vector defining the start of the bounding box
# vector2                     the vector defining the end of the bounding box
def IsInBoundingVectors(vector_check, vector1, vector2):
    # if vector_check is either bigger or smaller than both other, it does not lie between them
    # in that case it won't be inside the bounding box; hence return false
    for i in range(0, 3):
        if (vector_check[i] < vector1[i] and vector_check[i] < vector2[i]
            or vector_check[i] > vector1[i] and vector_check[i] > vector2[i]):
            return False
    return True



def SelectObjectsInBound(vector1, vector2):
    # deselect all
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    # cycle through all objects in the scene
    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        # check if the object is in the bounding vectors
        # if yes, select it
        # if no, deselect it
        if(IsInBoundingVectors(obj.matrix_world.to_translation(), vector1, vector2)):
            obj.select = True
        else:
            obj.select = False


SelectObjectsInBound(Vector((0, 0, -5)), Vector((10, 15, 15)))
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. Since i'm a fairly new python-scripter, could you tell me why the vector check is used?

Comment: @AndreBredeweg Updated the code with comments.

Comment: This doesn't work on blender 3.5 anymore. Any chance of an updated answer please? I'm pretty much asking the same thing on my question:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/297578/python-select-an-object-inside-a-cubic-area-and-rename-it?noredirect=1#comment513293_297578